# Live-updating jquery marquee

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a pseudo-marquee with jquery, looking like the one on the twitter home page. The ideal features would be :

- Using an HTML list to work
- Updating with Ajax when less than X elements remains to display
- Stopping on mouse over with callback

Does that exist somewhere, or should I just create it myself ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great [plugins](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/) for this, not necessarily using lists.

There's also [this one](http://alexfish.heroku.com/posts/21), which uses a sliding or fading effect...but could be tweaked into animating in another way.  It can be used on lists.

A plugin like jQuery Marquee will not carry out the Ajax for you, but it could be easily modified using other jQuery methods to update live.

The biggest thing to remember here is that if you set up your Ajax on an interval and continually modify the marquee's source DOM elements in the Ajax callback, you can achieve this effect without having to make yourself too crazy.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I would need one which displays multiple elements at the same time (like Twitter in fact) and not just one.
I'll see if I can modify one in that way...

Answer (score 2):

This is what ultimately worked for me:

```
 http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.cfm
```

When you want to update the list

elements, simply call the update function:

```
$("#id").marquee("update")
```